# How to integrate testcafejs in jenkins with different browsers

Tags: testing, jenkins, automated-tests, testcafe

Currently, I am doing automation UI tests with testcafejs for React project.

I would like to run these tests in continuous integration environments such as Jenkins. I already add browserStack plugin to run them locally with different browsers and operating system.

However, I would like to integrate them into Jenkins but not always consuming browserStack quota for daily checks. Any suggestions for how to run them within different browsers in Jenkins?

Comment: There is a KB article that describes how to integrate TestCafe with Jenkins: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T101087/how-to-integrate-testcafe-with-jenkins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TestCafe has an extensive command line interface that allows it to fit well in any popular continuous integration system.

Here are instructions on how you can integrate TestCafe with Jenkins. The up-to-date KB article can be found in this documentation topic for the [TestCafe Open Source](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/) version:

[Integrating TestCafe with Jenkins CI System](http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/integrating-testcafe-with-ci-systems/jenkins.html)

If you are using the legacy [TestCafe version](http://testcafe.devexpress.com) (version 15.1), you can use the following KB article:

[How to integrate TestCafe with Jenkins](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T101087/how-to-integrate-testcafe-with-jenkins)

You may also wish to check [the TestCafe plugin for Jenkins](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/media/team-blog/introducing-the-testcafe-jenkins-plugin.html) that attaches screenshots and videos to the Jenkins test results page.

### Step 1 - Fetching Test Code From a Repository

Here, we will use tests published in a separate repository on GitHub - [ci-integration-demo](https://github.com/VasilyStrelyaev/ci-integration-demo). If you use a different version control system, search for a plugin that integrates it with Jenkins.

Open your project and choose **Configure** from the right pane.

[image: Configure project]

Scroll down to the **Source Code Management** section and select Git, then specify the **Repository URL**.

[image: Check out tests]

### Step 2 - Adding a Command to Install TestCafe

Go to the **Build** section, find a step that builds you application and add a new step right after it. To do this, click **Add build step** and select a step type that runs a shell command.

[image: Add butch command]

In the **Command** box, type the following.

```
npm install testcafe testcafe-reporter-xunit
```

This command installs the main `testcafe` module and a plugin that saves test run reports in the xUnit format.

[image: npm install command]

### Step 3 - Adding a Command to Run TestCafe

Add another step that executes a shell command after the previous one. This step will run TestCafe.

Type the following command.

```
node_modules/.bin/testcafe chrome tests/**/* -r xunit:res.xml
```

This runs TestCafe tests from the `tests` directory in Google Chrome. Test results are saved to the `res.xml` file in the xUnit format.

[image: Run tests command]

### Step 4 - Publishing Test Run Reports

Go to the Post-build Actions section and click **Add post-build action**. In the drop-down list, select **Publish JUnit test result report.**

[image: Adding a post build action]

In the **Test report XMLs** field, specify the test report file: `res.xml`.

[image: Publish test reports]

### Step 5 - Run the Test

Click **Save** and you will be navigated to the Project page.

Hit **Build Now** to build the project immediately.

[image: Project Build Now]

### Step 6 - View Test Results

In the **Build History** section of the **Project** page, click a build and select **Test Results** from the drop-down menu.

[image: Build History]

Jenkins will display a test run report where you can see general information about testing results. You can click individual tests for details.

[image: View Test Results]

Comment: Thanks for answering, I did that as well :)